# Write and read file

Tags: android

My application writes data (object) to a file. To test it in Android Studio, I used the emulator but this always gives an I/O-error. 
So I tested it with a real phone but it doesn't start.

Is there a way to directly test this on the emulator or is a real phone with memory absolutely necessary?

Comment: Can you post some error logs ?

Comment: Please provide some code or stack trace to clarify your issue

Answer (score 0):

Reading file "raw/banks":

```
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.banks);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("TAG",e.getMessage());
    }
```